# install (self-built binary) Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I want to run Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. Now the distro comes with 2.4 but I don't want that (migrating config files hell and no time).

So I downloaded and built the 2.2 version through Make.

OK so the install went well but now I can't start Apache.

I tried

```
service apache2 restart
```

That gives me: Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.

So I tried:

```
apachectl -k start
```

This give me: the program 'apachectl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install apache2.
But of course I do not want this because it will probably install 2.4 and I don't want that version.

When I type:

```
which apache2
```

I get /usr/sbin/apache2 which contains some 60MB file from July15 (probably 2.4).

So the question is, how can I finalize my config here, so I can use the installed Apache 2.2?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Build process**

The build process is split into 3 parts. Configure, make and make install.

During configure you can set a lot of parameters to configure how the make and make install should behave.

It is very common that the option `--prefix` is default set to `/usr/local`

My guess is therefore that you will find your Apache 2.2 installation under `/usr/local`, and `apachectl` is under `/usr/local/sbin/apachectl`.

**Init**

It is sometimes common for the developer/publisher of a software to include an `init` script. Have a look at the documentation that came with the "source-ball" (the tar.gz).

A possible solution is that you copy the `init` script that came with Apache 2.4, edit it to fit with Apache 2.2. And then use `systemctl` to start and enable it as usual.

A different solution is to download the deb-file for Apache 2.2 from an older Ubuntu, that came with Apache 2.2, and copy and edit the `init` script from that to fit your solution.

I would also remove Apache 2.4 from your system, if you intend to not use it. Just so you won't have to wonder what installation what file belongs to.

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it some other way. On 16.04, I downloaded the 2.2.31 from the Apache site.

I built it using the following configuration:

```
./configure --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-included-apr --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-load-all-modules --enable-rewrite --enable-proxy --enable-proxy_connect --enable-proxy_http --enable-proxy_ajp --enable-authn_alias --with-npm=prefork --enable-proxy_balancer --enable-proxy_ftp --enable-cache --enable-suexec --enable-disk_cache  > conf.txt
```

Then of course tweaking the httpd.conf and ssl.conf files.

After that I just run the ./httpd -k start

And it works !

note that I added the apache2 via apt-get but never removed it. This means that after system start, I need to kill the apache2 process. And then I am able to start apache2.2.

Comment: well, what did you tweak? Show complete work for it to be useful.